# Will I go to jail if I made an Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: internet, software

I am a programmer, I'm always using different programming languages to make something like a hobby or just my playground.

Now I have several insights of how can I make an Artificial Intelligence, and before making something, a question pop up to my mind, will I go to jail if I accidentally made one?

I mean, my purpose of making it is educational, but since it is AI, it has its own learning system and can be a threat onto something or anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: You might get the Nobel prize.

Comment: I heard Facebook made a similar one, and they (panicly) stopped it immediately because of that unknown threat might take over the system.

Comment: Real life AI does not work "intelligently", it just work "as if it were intelligent", in general in a very specific context/problem. Of course, an important part of this is that we still do not know how intelligence works. The films about "evil AIs" that are like persons and urban legends like the Facebook one are just updated revisions of the myth of Frankenstein (which in turn, is a reedition of older ideas like those present in the stories of the golem, Prometheus and even the Genesis).

Comment: I don't mean AI as the ordinary AI, but an artificial mind, self learning, etc. I actually made a prototype but it is in alpha, the AI increases the priority level each time he gets fail onto something . and it also copies some function that he can read (though I don't want to further discuss). BTW, this is Law, not Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hello Shizukura!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) page.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly not.  My "almost" is because it is theoretically possible that your jurisdiction has a law which outlaws the development of AI.  To check for that, see if any of the universities in your jurisdiction have AI groups in the Computer Science department.  If they do, you can be pretty confident that it is legal.

(Aside: the chances of a lone hobbyist developing an AI more successfully than dedicated university groups or large corporations like Facebook and Google is minimal; but that doesn't affect the legality.)

Answer (score -5):

If you develop a device that may undermine, let's say, a company on a particular fragment of a certain field you will either be sued in case you put it on the market, or you'll be likely be damaged physically (i.e get rid out of) from a person related to that company (this stuff happens more often than you might think). I don't know the exact legal and jurisdictional implications that this thing might have, but for sure if there's some sort concurrence or competition, be sure that some companies play dirty games, both legally and illegally, even if it involves only a little part of their process.